# I keep getting the same numbers with my random number generator? (C++)

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program that gives 5 addition problems. The numbers are supposed to be randomly generated for the 5 problems. I keep getting the same numbers after the first loop. For example, is the first problem is "2+2=" then it will be the same problem for the next 4 times.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdlib>  
#include <ctime> 
using namespace std; 

void additionProblem(int topNumber, int bottomNumber) 
{ 
  int userAnswer; 
  cout << "\n\n\n      " << topNumber << " + " << bottomNumber << " = "; 
  cin >> userAnswer; 
  cin.ignore(1000, 10); 

  int theAnswer = topNumber + bottomNumber; 
  if (theAnswer == userAnswer) 
    cout << "      Correct!" << endl; 
  else 
    cout << "      Very good, but a better answer is " << theAnswer << endl; 

} // additionProblem 


int main() 
{ 
  srand(time(0));
  int number;
  int number2;
  number = rand() % 11; 
  number2 = rand() % 11;

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i != 5; i = i +1)
 {
    additionProblem(number, number2); 
  } 
} // main
```

Comment: Note the comment in the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand): `// Note: 1+rand()%6 is wrong!`. So please do not use modulo `%`

Comment: `number` and `number2` don't change in the loop.. instead you can directly use `rand()%11` inside the loop `additionProblem(rand()%11, rand()%11);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your random number generation is not inside your loop, so you only generate random numbers once.

To fix:

```
int main() 
{ 
  srand(time(0));

  for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
  {
    int number = rand() % 11; 
    int number2 = rand() % 11;

    additionProblem(number, number2); 
  } 
}
```